# Error when using a case expression in a where clause

Tags: sql-server

I am doing this

```
select *
from tabl 
WHERE (
    CASE WHEN tbl.mydate IS NOT NULL 
    THEN tbl.mydate > tbl2.mydate
    ELSE 1=1 
    END
)
```

but getting an error as follows

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 42
> Incorrect syntax near '>'.
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 57
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Comment: Its a case expression, not a case statement, you can only return a value from it, not a condition.

Comment: Where is `tbl` and `tbl2` defined?

Comment: Notice how "AS" is not actually in your query, nor is tbl or tbl2. You make things much more difficult when the code you post is not actually the code you are using (or is just a snippet from a larger query). And there is no avoiding the effort needed to learn the language.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about what's on-topic in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Just use regular `AND`/`OR` logic e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM tabl 
WHERE tbl.mydate IS NULL
OR tbl.mydate > tbl2.mydate
```

Note: In SQL Server its a case expression, not a case statement, you can only return a value from it, not a condition.

Comment: but that does not give me the right data, if i use OR, it still shows NULL, but if i remove the OR condition, it displays the record

Comment: @Jimlee Well firstly, show your complete query, and secondly show some sample data. Because the logic I have provided is the same as your logic.